# Active Directory - Restrict User to login only one PC at a time

Tags: user-accounts, active-directory, group-policy

I want to implement a policy which is related to specific users on domain. What I want to achieve is:

If a user login, let's say, to PC1 he should not be able to use any other PC using his credentials until he logs out from PC1.

Is it possible to create such rule and force update via Active Directory not on user properties one-by-one? I don't want to bind user to one PC just any PC but force login to only one PC at a time.

Comment: Have you seen [this guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37839.active-directory-limit-concurrent-user-logins.aspx)?

Comment: Just add a link of detailed steps to install and use LimitLogin which might help you. LimitLogin: Step By Step https://rahuldpatel.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/limitlogin-step-by-step/

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory doesn't provide this functionality.

You could enforce this limitation using the Technet script
[Limit concurrent logins in Active Directory](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Limit-concurrent-logins-in-dc13d8cb?stoAI=10&wa=wsignin1.0&stoAI=10),
further detailed in the article
[Active Directory: Limit concurrent user logins](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37839.active-directory-limit-concurrent-user-logins.aspx),
using logon and logoff scripts with a file used as lock.

Another similar method is detailed in the article
[Restrict Multiple Logins in Domain (AD)](https://abhishek.nagar.me/blogs/restrict-multiple-logins-domain-ad),
using logon and logoff batch scripts.

You could also try the very old utility
[LimitLogin](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/cc160794(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN),
although I do not know if it will work on newer versions of Windows.